# finding primary decomposition of an ideal and embedded primes

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

Let $R = k[u, v, x, y]$ and $I = (ux, vy, uy + vx)$. What will be the primary decomposition of $I$?

My try:

The ideal $(u,v)$ and $(x,y)$ is the minimal prime ideal of $I$. And so the radical $\sqrt{I}=(u,v)\cap (x,y)$. So certainly they are minimal associated primes of $I$.

Now, what will be the other embedded primes? Also, what will be primary decomposition of $I$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690) `R=QQ[u,v,x,y]`
`I=ideal(u*x,v*y,u*y+v*x)` `associatedPrimes I -- {ideal(v,u), ideal(y,x), ideal(y,x,v,u)}` 
`primaryDecomposition I -- {ideal(v,u), ideal(y,x), ideal(y^2,v*y,x^2,v*x+u*y,u*x,v^2,u^2)}`